# How to set the path to the file in the project?

Tags: json, reactjs, meteor, markdown

If you keep the full path, then everything works. But this will not work, as it should be run on other computers.

My attempts to write the path:

```
const jsonData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/app/data/faqQuestions', { encoding: 'utf8' }));
```

Issues in the console:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\app\data\faqQuestions.json'
```

If you remove the slash before: `app/data/faqQuestions.json`:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\mi\AppData\Local\Temp\meteor-test-runqxi9h2.08bd.meteor\local\build\programs\server\app\data\faqQuestions.json'
```

It is necessary to prescribe the correct path to work on any computer.
I need something like PWD.

Comment: Is `/app/data/` a relative path in your Meteor project or is it outside of your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `path` module in node to get the correct path in the filesystem:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const filepath = path.resolve('/app/data');
const jsonFile = fs.readFileSync(path.join(filepath, 'faqQuestions.json'), { encoding: 'utf8' });
const jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonFile);
console.log('data', jsonData);
```

Comment: Thanks for your option, but it gives an error
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C: \ app \ data \ faqQuestions.json'

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You shouldn't be accessing the file system directly like this. There are a couple of reasons for it:

1) Locations will vary from computer to computer
2) When deployed to a docker container in production, the local file system is read-only, unless you specifically mount a volume for such purposes
3) When Meteor is built, the bundle it runs is somewhere in .meteor/local..., so you can't really use pwd

It makes more sense to store files either in external storage (like an S3 bucket, see ostrio:files for how to do this), or to put them in your Mongo database as objects.

If you are still determined to access the files from the file system, you can specify a location in Meteor.settings, which means that you can set that up independently for each server/computer you are running on.

Answer (score 0):

you may place your files e.g. inside the "private" directory of your application sources, like

./private/data/faq.json

To get that content you may use:

```js
// use for file access
var fs = Npm.require('fs');

// using this meteor lib, gives secure access to folder structure
var files = Npm.require("./mini-files");

// save reference to serverDir
var serverDir = files.pathResolve(__meteor_bootstrap__.serverDir);

// Taken from meteor/tools/bundler.js#L1509
// currently the directory structure has not changed for build
var assetBundlePath = files.pathJoin(serverDir, 'assets', 'app');

// location of the private data folder
var dataPath = files.pathJoin(assetBundlePath, 'data');
```

after that it should be possible to load your json on server like

```js
const jsonData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(files.pathJoin(dataPath, 'faqQuestions'), { encoding: 'utf8' }));
```

I used that in a component for meteor to work with ENV config files located at Github (https://github.com/4commerce-technologies-AG/meteor-package-env-settings)

Cheers